# Is there a way to produce a binary diff on two byte arrays in c# .net?

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, algorithm

I am trying to compare two byte arrays in memory and produce a data structure to hold the differences so that with byte array B and the data structure holding the differences it is possible to recreate byte array A.

The size of the byte arrays are always identical and are relatively small.  The byte arrays represent bitmaps which typically range in size from 1000x1000x32 to 128x128x32.

The speed and efficiency (from a cpu time pov) at which the data-structure-that-holds-the-differences and the second byte array can be combined/used to reconstruct byte array A is of the highest importance.  It is not as important that the generation of the difference object be as efficient.

Right now my solution will be to use a binary search + md5 hashing approach to build a list of the smallest units of difference inside the image and package the raw byte data with a reference of its offset inside byte array A.

I.e. I generate the hash for Image A's byte array and compare it to the hash of Image B's byte array, if it doesn't match I horizontally split the image in half and hash each block then compare those hashes between the images, this process is then repeated recursively until all blocks that don't match hit a minimum size like 32x32x32 and/or a max number of splits.  Once a block is marked as matching it is no longer part of the recursive search.  Once all the differences have been identified they will be added to a list of changes and that list is then the difference object.

Are there any built in ways to efficiently produce the results I'm looking for?  Or are there any libraries that would do the job?

---

**Notes:**

- This is a learning project (for WCF, WPF and a number of other technologies),
- It is a VNC style system - so the images are snapshots of a window and will be sent over a LAN connection.
- The reason the reconstructing of Byte array A must be efficient is that a client can connect to more than one server and each server can serve more than one window, so a client could be monitoring/interacting with 30+ windows.
- I would like to achieve 3 fps+ in each window for any content that changes.

Comment: Can you post some example files and an expected size of the differences? I have a binary diff implementation, but I'm unsure it will fit your needs. If you could post an A and B example, I can test it and post an answer.

Comment: If you don't have a place to put unaltered files (for instance, Flickr and similar sites might not let you download the exact binaries you upload), send them to me by email, you can find it on my profile page in the text.

Comment: Ah, speed is more important than size of patch, well, never mind then :) My algorithm is the opposite, size of patch is most important, I use it for updating files over the network.

Comment: Algorithm that you provided above leads to data loss. The fact that hash for one array (or part) equals hash for other array (part) does not mean they are equal.

Comment: What is the main purpose: storing information to compress size? If compressing is not required, the fastest way to store would be to do the opposite: save both A and B, and generate differences if needed. If that's true (you are trying to save space), then how many differences are expected to be there on average? How are they expected to be distributed? Maybe there exist some patterns in your data or differences? E.g., large blocks of differences of the same magnitude or in the same bit positions, etc.

Comment: I think you should post the examples anyway, and some expectations, like how long you would expect the diff to run, and how much data you expect it to produce.

Comment: I have updated the main question with some additional information for you guys! (thanks for the interest so far!!) :D

Comment: Is there any way you can post two example screenshots, with some differences that you expect to run at 3fps?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If they're guaranteed to be the same size - actually, the same dimensions - then I'm not seeing the importance of all this hashing and binary searches and other overhead.  You can simply compare the two byte-by-byte in a loop, and if they don't match, add a "point" to your diff containing both the index and the value in A.  To reverse the process, you don't need to look at every byte because you already have indexes.

If the two arrays differ by, say, just 1 byte, then you'll end up with a diff structure that's 5 bytes in size (assuming you use an Int32 for the index), and takes exactly 1 iteration to mutate B back into A.  In general the process is O(n) for the diff and O(*m*) for the revert, where *m* is the total number of points that actually changed.  I'm not an expert on data structures but I doubt you'll be able to come up with something more efficient.

So, something like this:

```
Diff GetDiff(byte[] a, byte[] b)
{
    Diff diff = new Diff();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] != b[i])
        {
            diff.Points.Add(new DiffPoint(i, a[i]));
        }
    }
    return diff;
}

// Mutator method - turns "b" into the original "a"
void ApplyDiff(byte[] b, Diff diff)
{
    foreach (DiffPoint point in diff.Points)
    {
        b[point.Index] = point.Value;
    }
}

// Copy method - recreates "a" leaving "b" intact
byte[] ApplyDiffCopy(byte[] b, Diff diff)
{
    byte[] a = new byte[b.Length];
    int startIndex = 0;
    foreach (DffPoint point in diff.Points)
    {
        for (int i = startIndex; i < point.Index; i++)
        {
            a[i] = b[i];
        }
        a[point.Index] = point.Value;
        startIndex = point.Index + 1;
    }
    for (int j = startIndex; j < b.Length; j++)
    {
        a[j] = b[j];
    }
    return a;
}

struct DiffPoint
{
    public int Index;
    public byte Value;

    public DiffPoint(int index, byte value) : this()
    {
        this.Index = index;
        this.Value = value;
    }
}

class Diff
{
    public Diff()
    {
        Points = new List<DiffPoint>();
    }

    public List<DiffPoint> Points { get; private set; }
}
```

There's a lot of looping in the `ApplyDiffCopy` but if you work it out you'll see that it actually only performs one operation per point.  Of course, if you don't need a copy and just want to mutate B, then the first `ApplyDiff` method will be extremely fast if there aren't many actual differences.

And obviously I haven't done much error-checking here.  You would want to write your version a bit more defensively (verify array lengths, etc.)

If I've correctly understood the assumptions here and the problem you're trying to solve, then the original `ApplyDiff` method is going to be the fastest way to restore the original image.

Comment: +1. I have found that your code provided better solution than mine, and was published earlier. That's why I deleted my answer.

Comment: I would suggest using pointer arithmetics with unsafe code for higher speed.

And please make your answer shorter (especially code). It looks like people can't see its benefits behind lots of information, or just don't read it to the end - and vote for other answers.

Anyway it's your answer, please don't treat my suggestion as telling you what to do. :)

Comment: +1. Looks like a complete answer given the information that was provided.

Comment: This solution is great - I didn't accept it right away as I was looking into the RLE of the XOR of the two arrays.  Thank you for taking the time to post such a complete solution.

Comment: Unsafe code removes array bounds checking so it will improve performance; it also makes it absolutely critical to perform the appropriate parameter validation at the beginning.  As for shortening the code, I'm not really sure how to do that without removing something important, but I'll move the class declarations to the bottom to make the algorithms more obvious.

Comment: For big differences, this will produce more data than just shipping the new image verbatim. For instance, scrolling a website just one pixel up will produce massive amounts of single-pixel-differences. Are you sure this is what you want? What about posting example screenshots so we can give you some real data?

Comment: I agree, and I could suggest all kinds of optimizations and compression strategies (I've had to implement them in the past), but if this is going to be used in production then it would be better to simply license an off-the-shelf protocol like Blaze or use an open-source one like rdesktop.  Why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 2):

Crikey! - that's all a bit complex, what's wrong with a run length encoding of the XOR of the two arrays - does the encoding and decoding in one pass and should be reasonably efficient in space as most of the values will be zero, but you could re-compress the RLE data further if required.

Comment: XOR is wholly unsuitable to such things, unless it's impossible to get a real diff-engine to run with high enough speed. Just scrolling a website one pixel in any direction will produce massive amounts of differences, and those differences, due to XOR, will be worse to compress than just compressing the new image without diffing it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the BitArray class (or use Reflector to see how it's implemented so you don't get copying of your arrays in order to speed it up even more)

```
        byte[] s1 = new byte[] {0,1,2,3,4,5,6};
        byte[] s2 = new byte[] {0,1,2,4,4,6,6};
        var orig1 = new BitArray(s1);
        var orig2 = new BitArray(s2);
        var diff = orig1.Xor(orig2);
        byte[] diffArray = new byte[s1.Length];
        diff.CopyTo(diffArray, 0); // here we have a byte diff array of s1 and s2

        var reconstruct = orig2.Xor(diff);
        reconstruct.CopyTo(diffArray, 0); // diffArray is now the same as s1
```